# Marshalling array of structures from C#

Tags: c#, interop

I have a requirement where I need to marshal an array of structures from managed code(c#) to native code(C++). The structure is something like

```
//need to put any attributes here?

public struct inner
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public long l1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public long l2;
}

public struct outer
{    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    public string s1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int i1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public int i2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public long l1;
    // How can I marshal an array of structures here?
    public inner[] array1;
}
```

My requirement is to return an array of the struct outer :)

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in Advance,
-Mani.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after StructLayoutKind.Sequential ?

[MSDN Struct Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471(VS.71).aspx)

[StructLayoutKind reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the unmanaged declarations and the associated semantics expected by the corresponding methods which uses them, it impossible to tell, but you will need:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst=10)] //change size as per your needs
public inner[] array1;
```

OR

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=10)] //change size as per your needs
public inner[] array1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a C++/CLI assembly to your project. That's the easiest way to do interop with C++. Then you can directly include all your .h files and link to any .lib files. But you're still i .NET-land. C++/CLI is very similar to C#. You just have to type a ""^ after all your managed classes and you use "->" instead of "." but that's about it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the pointer of the memory block occupied by the entire array. The solution of this exact problem is explained in this [post](http://blog.lavgupta.com/2008/07/marshalling-array-of-structures_1430.html).